# Why was my edit on a class import rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25930158) was my suggested edit on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55834112/). The reason for the rejection was:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I don't see how any of those reasons apply. The user would need to import `webdriver` class from selenium, otherwise that script is not runnable.

Comment: The edit was rejected by the author of the post.

Comment: The author rejected this themselves. I cannot actually say if this code would work or not but there is a comment that says that it does work. Also, it has 18 upvotes, so it has been useful to at least 18 people.

Comment: You should generally try to avoid editing code. Editing is for [improving grammar and spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: @RobertLongson But that code needs editing, because some people might not know that you need to import `webdriver` from `selenium` for the script to run.

Comment: @VLAZ yep, it has 18 upvotes, but that doesn't mean it can't be improved

Comment: @Snow then write your own answer if you think you can do better.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think a better idea would be to add a comment to the answer, if the op doesn't want to accept my edit.

Comment: @yivi sorry for the confusion

Comment: @gnat Hi, thanks for the link. Yes, it does answer my question. Unfortunately, it does not contradict my edit. So I don't get why the op has rejected it :/ But eh, I won't dwell on it any longer

Comment: Note that the author of the answer has now included your edit suggestion himself.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille haha oh well